# music rich snippet - soundcloud or other

Tags: soundcloud, code-snippets

Is there a way to code the soundcloud embedded player (flash) with rich snippets so the player displays in search results? Failing this is there a decent tutorial somewhere for this purpose with just mp3 files? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have google webmaster tools, you can access this page:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170

And here is a tutorial on the music rich snippet:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1623047

(that link can be found on the first page I linked above, along with other rich snippet types for other data)

I hope that helps! :)